# How can I view/edit my users' Google Calendar Events using my NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, google-api, next.js, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am building a platform using NextJS in which I need to grab my users' Google Calendar events and be able to add events to their calendars.

I have a service account set up and would like my service account to access my users' calendar data.

After researching, I have found that one way to do so is to have the user share their calendar manually with my service account.

However, I was wondering if there is a way for my users to be able to give my service account permission without having to do it manually, so for example, pressing a button on my platform that will let them share their calendar with the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) are intended for use with a calendar that you the developer control.  Service accounts also only work with google calendar if you have a google workspace account. You will also need to use a google workspace domain account in order to set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) on your service account to use it with google calendar.

There is no way for a user to share a standard google calendar account with a service account.  That was shut down by google a number of years ago.  The only option now is [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

That being said you will need to use Oauth2 to request consent of your users to access their google calendar accounts. Something like this would be a good place to start [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I already have my google workspace account set up with a service account. I was not too sure about the Oauth2 and how it works. So basically, by using an Oauth2 Service Account, I can ask for my users' permission and then edit/view their calendars on their behalf?

Comment: No by using Oauth2 you can request user consent to access their personal calendar accounts.   By using a service account you could configure an application to access a single calendar account without require consent.   You may want to watch this it tells you all about service accounts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTTTtwb7x7g

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the fast response!